# Is it better to display all products or use a carousel on a responsive website?

Tags: mobile, lists, e-commerce, responsive-design, carousel

I have two versions for displaying products in an e-commerce website (responsive):

**Long version (all shown):**

[image]

**Short version (with carousel):**

[image]

I am having a dilemma which to use. On one hand the long version shows everything and the user only needs to scroll down. But it just looks and feels long. If I use the carousel, the users need to scroll vertically and horizontally but it looks cleaner.

If I were to use the longer version, is there a better way to display it so it doesn't look like there's too much to scroll on the page? Or should I just use the carousel?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at your sketches it appears as a landing page; here the carousel version works best, because the **business need is to show users more sections to go through** without too much of vertical scroll. **Once the user chooses a particular category you can switch the layout to long vertical scroll**, here the users may not mind scrolling down because they are looking for the exact thing they need.

---

Examples:

## Landing:

[image]

## Category:

[image]